# How can I test a method which aggregates data from a database?

Tags: java, database, web, junit

I'm developing the web Java application and come across the following issue:

I'm using jUnit 4.5.

Suppose that I have a method which aggregates data from a database for the rendering their to a markup. Is it make a sense to testing an sql query in the way that I simple write a series of sql-queries and compare expected and real results?

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A unit test should test the unit you are dealing with and not other units (that's what integration, regression, load, or acceptance tests are for).

The method you are testing has the job to issue SQL queries and receive the results. Therefore, its unit test should exercise that behaviour and verify it. Whether that means using a real database, an in-memory test database or a completely fake mock database that does nothing but respond with canned results depends on which is easiest to do. The important point is that you verify "a SELECT ID FROM PUPILS WHERE... goes out, and the results are stored or returned".

Comment: That's a unit test shouldn't exercise the result of a specifiec sql-query? It just check the query can be executed and the result can be received, right?

Comment: It should definitely check that a query goes out, and probably that it is a SELECT query. It *might* also verify that whatever the circumstances are, the SQL syntax is actually valid, although you'd need a verifier component for that - either a list of acceptable queries, a set of patterns to match, of a full-fledged SQL parser (although that's pushing it). It should probably *not* verify that "sending this SQL actually retrieves the three right pupils" because that depends much more on the database engine than on your SQL issuer.

Comment: Interesting, thank you. But I would also clarify if I'm working for a method that's executed user's payment-transaction the unit test for that method should test the facility to execute such transactions on the test wallets, test users, etc... Am I right?